# Unable to simplify complex expression

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I am very new to Mathematica. Somehow Mathematica doesn't give me the norm expression, instead, it just gives the original expression. How should I fix this? The code is:

```
ClearAll[r];

expr = (-6 r^4 + 16 r^2 + 5)/(9 r^6 + 4 r^4 - 4 r + 1) + ((
     7 r^3 - 8 r)/(9 r^6 + 4 r^4 - 4 r^2 + 1)) I;

ComplexExpand@Norm@expr
```

which gives me the result as:

```
(*Abs[(5+16 r^2-6 r^4)/(1-4 r+4 r^4+9 r^6)+(\[ImaginaryI] (-8 r+7 \
r^3))/(1-4 r^2+4 r^4+9 r^6)]*)
```

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code.

Comment: The above are all the relevant code

Comment: You should post plaint text code.  One can't copy code from an image to try it.  But your error is that you used `Norm`. You should use `Abs` instead, then it works.

Answer (score 4):

If you are very new to Mathematica, I suggest you take the [Fast Introduction from the official Wolfram Website](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/)

As, far as your problem is concerned, @Nasser has already provided the solution in the comments. I will just highlight one more way and some subtleties:

In your code:

```
ClearAll[r];

expr = (-6 r^4 + 16 r^2 + 5)/(9 r^6 + 4 r^4 - 4 r + 1) + ((
     7 r^3 - 8 r)/(9 r^6 + 4 r^4 - 4 r^2 + 1)) I;

ComplexExpand@Norm@expr
```

Just make a tiny change like this and you will get the same answer as using direct `Abs`, which is:

```
ComplexExpand@Norm@{expr}
```

and you will get the same result.

$$\sqrt{\frac{\left(-6 r^4+16 r^2+5\right)^2}{\left(9 r^6+4 r^4-4 r+1\right)^2}+\frac{\left(7 r^3-8 r\right)^2}{\left(9 r^6+4 r^4-4 r^2+1\right)^2}}$$

The theoretical difference between the two is beautifully explained in this [MathStackExchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16167/1024032). You should have a look for a better understanding.